# NestJs and Couchbase integration

Tags: javascript, nestjs, couchbase

I'm looking for information and code examples about how to integrate NestJs with a Couchbase database.

I'd like to explore the options of using either the Couchbase SDK directly or the [Ottoman ODM](https://docs.couchbase.com/nodejs-sdk/current/hello-world/start-using-ottoman.html)

Regards,